# Insert a predefined list variable into a new list in tcl

Tags: list, tcl

I'm trying to insert a variable that contains a list into a list using tcl. So far I have:

```
set $a {1 2 3}
set $b {4 5 6}

set foo(bar) {{$a} {$b}}
puts foo(bar)
```

Which returns:

```
{$a} {$b}
```

How can I insert two nested list that the variables represent? I.E. return:

```
{1 2 3} {4 5 6}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [list](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/list.htm) command if you are creating a new list

```
set a {1 2 3}
set b {3 4 5}
set bar [list $a $b]
```

If you are *inserting* into an existing list you should use [linsert](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/linsert.htm):

```
set c {7 8 9}
set bar [linsert $bar 1 $c]
```